# @HostListener('window:keydown') vs @HostListener('window:keydown.arrowup') + @HostListener('window:keydown.arrowdown')?

Tags: angular, keyboard-events

When we want to listen to two keys (arrowUp and arrowDown in this case) what would perform better, one listener per key, or one generic?

I'm having keyboard input lag sometimes and my approach now is to narrow down the scope of `@HostListener('window:keydown')` events spread around the code to only be triggered when it's their time (instead of checking for the key that was pressed inside the listener function), but I'm uncertain of the best solution.
Can someone shed some light on it?
Thanks.

PS: I'm using Angular 7

Comment: I don't know how to measure the preference but `@HostListener('window:keydown')` = `window.addEventListener('keydown', fnMatchesAnything, false)` and `@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowup')` = `window.addEventListener('keydown', fnMatchesArrowup, false)` and again for arrow down. So its one `window.addEventListener` vs two and angular code filtering the keys vs your own. I imagine the difference isn't a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowup',['$event'])
 @HostListener('window:keydown.arrowdown',['$event'])`

should perform better since there is less code to be processed when the events are triggered. If you put a listener on all `keydown` events and filter manually, there would be more tasks.

Comment: I opted by splitting the code into two Host Listeners, one for arrowUp and another for arrowDown. I'll update the thread when this is deployed and I can see if it improves it for the users.